# Json encode error in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I tried to load a view in my codeigniter controller and also i pass a status to my ajax function. In the ajax function i wrote a sweetalert popup in the sucess function when my status is 1. now my actual problem is when i load a view in the controller the status is not passing to my ajax function.can anyone figureout what the problem is any help is appreciable.

> controller

```
$query = $this->package_view_model->enquiry_history();
    if (isset($query))
      {
        $status = 1;
        $this->load->view('packages/enquiry');
      }
    echo json_encode (array("status"=>$status));
```

> ajax function

```
function sendMail(package_url)
{   
    var formData = $("#enqform").serialize();
      jQuery.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: '<?php echo base_url() ?>tour-package/send-mail',
          data: formData,
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(data){
            if(data.status == 1){
                swal({
                       title:'Thankyou for your interest!!!',
                       text: "Our excecutives will contact you soon.",
                       html: true,
                       type: "success",
                       showCancelButton: false,
                       showConfirmButton:false
                   });
                window.setTimeout(function() {
                    window.location.href = '<?php echo base_url() ?>tour-packages';
                }, 1000000);
            }
          }
      }); 
      return false;
      e.preventDefault();
  }
```

Comment: You're sending `formData` in the request; what does that contain? You say you have an error, what does it say?

Comment: i  didnt put the whole code, here i send some values from a form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this will help you :

```
$query = $this->package_view_model->enquiry_history();
$status = 1;
if (! empty($query))
{ 
   $this->load->view('packages/enquiry');
}
echo json_encode(array("status" => $status));
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem with the ending slash in the baseurl. So, change the way you're generating the url.

```
function sendMail(package_url)
{   
    var formData = $("#enqform").serialize();
      jQuery.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: '<?php echo base_url("tour-package/send-mail") ?>',
          data: formData,
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(data){
            if(data.status == 1){
                swal({
                       title:'Thankyou for your interest!!!',
                       text: "Our excecutives will contact you soon.",
                       html: true,
                       type: "success",
                       showCancelButton: false,
                       showConfirmButton:false
                   });
                window.setTimeout(function() {
                    window.location.href = '<?php echo base_url() ?>tour-packages';
                }, 1000000);
            }
          }
      }); 
      return false;
      e.preventDefault();
  }
```

Comment: i tried this is not the problem i think the problem is in json encode in controller.